# cocoa nstextfielddelegate EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to hook a `NSTextField` to a `NSTextFieldDelegate` to implement the `controlTextDidChange`.

```
// TFDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TFDelegate : NSObject <NSTextFieldDelegate>

@end

// TFDelegate.m
#import "TFDelegate.h"

@implementation TFDelegate

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"controlTextDidChange");
}

@end

// ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  TFDelegate *del = [[TFDelegate alloc] init];
  [self.TimeInput setDelegate:del];
}
```

As soon as I start typing something in the `TimeInput`-NSTextField, my app crashed with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I don't see why my app would try to access memory that doesn't exist? Did I do something wrong with the instantation/allocation of my `TFDelegate`?

Comment: can you add full text of error?

Comment: Xcode pauses at:
0x7fff9f24c235 <+1>: movl   %eax, %edi
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400250006).
Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach?

Comment: [self.TimeInput setDelegate:del];  ???